# Extjs 3: why don't fire keypress, blur, keyup event in EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

This what i try to fire event keypress, blur, keyup, mousedown event in EditorGridPanel. but in bellow code only show `mousedown` alert

```
    grid.on('render', function(){
   var view = grid.getView();

   view.on('blur', function(e, t){
      alert('blur');
   },this);

   view.on('keyup', function(e, t){
      alert('keyup');
   },this);         

   view.on('keypress', function(e, t){
      alert('keypress');
   },this);

   view.mainBody.on('mousedown', function(e, t){
      alert('mousedown');
   },this);

}, this);
```

how can i fire keypress, blur, keyup event in editor grid

Answer (score 1):

The grid view does not fire these events. Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView) for the list of events of a component.

You probably want to add your events to the editor field.

Comment: thanks for your advice. how can i get my grid editor form grid?